# Simple ChoiceField error

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to achieve a rather simple thing, but got stuck with an error and have no idea where does it come from.

I want to create and save an object in my views. The code is very simple:

models.py:

```
class Iteration(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
one_two = '1-2 weeks'
two_four = '2-4 weeks'
four_six = '4-6 weeks'
six_eight = '6-8 weeks'
DURATION_CHOICES = (
    (one_two, '1-2 weeks'),
    (two_four, '2-4 weeks'),
    (four_six, '4-6 weeks'),
    (six_eight, '6-8 weeks'),
)

duration = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DURATION_CHOICES, default=two_four)
project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

def is_upperclass(self):
    return self.duration in (self.one_two, self.six_eight)
```

views.py:

```
def New_iteration(request, slug):
form = IterationForm()
user = request.user
project = Project.objects.get(user=user, slug=slug)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = IterationForm(request.POST)
    errors = form.errors
    if form.is_valid:
        user = request.user
        duration = request.POST['duration']
        project = Project.objects.get(user=user, slug=slug)
        new_iteration = Iteration(user.id, form.cleaned_data['duration'], project.id)
        new_iteration.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("not valid")
return render(request, "new_iteration.html", {"form" : form, "project" : project, "user" : user})
```

I am receiving an error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2-4 weeks'`. I think it comes from

`new_iteration = Iteration(user.id, form.cleaned_data['duration'], project.id)`

line, but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create the object as

```
new_iteration = Iteration(user.id, form.cleaned_data['duration'], project.id)
```

you need to pass data as keyword parameters as

```
new_iteration = Iteration(user = user, duration = form.cleaned_data['duration'], 
                          project = project)
```

However, I believe `IterationForm` is model form and you want to get `project` before saving the iteration, more better way is

```
if form.is_valid(): #note this is function call
    user = request.user
    project = Project.objects.get(user=user, slug=slug)
    new_iteration = form.save(commit=False)
    new_iteration.project = project
    new_iteration.save()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. After using your code (2nd variant) the form does not validate, I am getting errors, that 'user' and 'project' fields are required (they actually are.). I would like to mention why I am doing that: I want to get the current user from `request.user` and project from `slug`, so the user only has to enter the `duration`. Thats the thing that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: the code works fine with `new_iteration = Iteration(**form.cleaned_data)` , but I want to get the current user and project from request.user and slug :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the task. I should have added my forms.py for better understanding. I have edited my forms.py file and defined there, that the **only** "selectable" field should be "duration", and Django should get other stuff (user and project) when initiating the form in views.

The other mistake was that I did not pass data as keyword parameters,  thanks Rohan.

So I have added `fields = ('duration',)` to my ModelForm and re-initiaded the form with keyword arguments now.